# How to add/remove in Array inside dynamic Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I have a reducer with this structure:

```
{
  [key]: {
    answers: [
      { key: 1, mode: 'INCLUDE' }
    ],
    period: {},
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to add items to the answers-array, but this doesn't work (inside reducer). Because then each time the only existing array item is being replaced.

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.payload.serieId]: {
    ...state[action.payload.serieId],
    answers: [
      { ...action.payload.answerFilter },
    ],
  },
}
```

This also doesn't work, because the property ...state[action.payload.serieId].answers can't be found.

```
return {
  ...state, [action.payload.serieId]: 
  {
    ...state[action.payload.serieId],
    answers: [ 
      ...state[action.payload.serieId].answers
      { ...action.payload.answerFilter },
    ],
  },
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Is there some way to solve this inside the reducer or do I have to modify the entire Array outside and then simply set it in its entirety on each change?

"Answers" is an Array because there might be more than one filter in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a default value if `serieId` is not found into the reducer state, so it should be useful if you do something like

```
const currentSerie = state[action.payload.serieId] || generateStateFromScratch();
```

then you could do something like

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.payload.serieId]: {
    ...currentSerie,
    ...{
      answers: [ ...currentSerie.answers, { ...action.payload.answerFilter } ]
    }
  }
}
```

so you `generateStateFromScratch` function should like look this

```
const generateStateFromScratch = () => ({
    answers: [
      { key: 1, mode: 'INCLUDE' }
    ],
    period: {}
})
```

> You can return an empty `answers` array into the initial state if needed.

Comment: That is great, I really struggled with this one! Thanks! <3